Getting Buffer Validation newBufferWith must not exceed 256 MB error when I am trying to load model of 2.5 gb size
I have downloaded Google iOS sample of MediaPipe and tried to load my model which is 2.5 GB in size.
private var inference: LlmInference! = {
//
// let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "gemma-2b-it-gpu-int4", ofType: "bin")! 
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "slm1", ofType: "bin")!
    let llmOptions = LlmInference.Options(modelPath: path)
    return LlmInference(options: llmOptions)
}()

I am getting following error:
-[MTLDebugDevice newBufferWithBytes:length:options:]:670: failed assertion `Buffer Validation
newBufferWith*:length 0x1f400000 must not exceed 256 MB.

I have came to know that a single MTLBuffer is limited to a maximum length of 256MB. If we need a total allocation of more than 256 MB, we can allocate multiple buffers and split data among them, but I don't know how I will be able to do in case of this SDK.
